MySQL foreign key of subpart of primary key
I have this code in MySQL:
create table Expedition(
name varchar(20),
subject varchar(20),
timespan float,
location varchar(20),
represid int,
organid int,
persid int,
constraint expedition_primary primary key(name,subject,timespan,location,represid,organid,persid)  
);
create table Organiser(
organiserid int,
primary key(organiserid),
foreign key(organiserid) references Expedition(expedition_primary(organid)),  
);
create table Representator(
representatorid int,
primary key(representatorid),
foreign key(representatorid) references Expedition(expedition_primary(represid)),
);
create table county(
cnName varchar(20),
cnid int,
primary key(cnName,cnid),
foreign key(cnid) references Organiser(organiserid),
);

What I want to do is that the link between the tables Organiser and Expedition is organiserid(Organiser) -> organid(Expedition).
But the primary key of the expedition is the expedition_primary which is not only the organid but other columns as well.So how can we write in SQL that the link is only organid?Thanks.

You can't - 'in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions

counry must  be the reference not organisation

@P.Salmon so how can I do this??

The foreign keys should be in expedition..

Ah okay thank you!I am quite new to this so any help is good.
